# Detect plugin's version number in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, citrix

In Firefox I can reference

```
navigator.plugins["myplugin"].version
```

but the property 'version' doesn't exist in chrome.  The particular plugin I'm working with is the Citrix Client Receiver plugin ([download here](http://www.citrix.nl/English/SS/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2304987&productId=186#top)).

Anyone know anything I don't about where or how else I might be able to get the version number of this plugin in Chrome using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to obtain the version number of a plugin in Chrome is to interpret the `name`:

```
//Example, Shockwave Flash
var version = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].name.match(/([\d.]+)/);
 //used semicolons (grouping) inside the Regular expression, to allow the
 // possibility of defining a more detailed/exact version position.

version = version ? version[1] : "";
```

Comment: Alas, Citrix isn't putting any version information into the name property.  I suppose I'm stuck, eh?

Comment: If you need a version-specific feature, use `try{ ..test.. }catch(e){/*not supported*/}` to test whether a feauture exists (and thus, is supported) or not.